# Requesting guidance in creating custom SeekBar in Android. (like shown in the image)

Tags: java, android, seekbar, android-seekbar

I have a task to create a SeekBar looking like this:

[image]

My question is: How to segment the seekbar like that? I have made custom seekbars before, but I don't know how to segment the bar like that, with lines extending beyond the seekbar's height.

I have stumbled across a library, the ComboSeekBar, but it doesn't help much.

Thanks in advance to anyone willing to help!

Cheers!

Comment: `setBackgroundDrawable()` could be an option, if you don't find more appropriate way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I already see two ways to do it

1. Using background `Drawable`

   Create and choose your seekbar drawable  using `setBackgroundDrawable()`.
2. Use third-party libraries:

> #### RangeSliderView: (min. SDK API 14):
>
> https://github.com/channguyen/range-slider-view
>
> [image]
>
> #### RangeSeekbar:
>
> https://github.com/dolphinwang/RangeSeekbar
>
> #### RangeBar:
>
> https://github.com/edmodo/range-bar

Check also this unfinished project: https://github.com/feelinglucky/RadioSeekBar

Hope it help

Comment: Thank you! I will try them now and deliver some feedback after! ^^

Comment: The RangeBar is exactly what I need, except is has 2 Thumbs, Do you happen to know if it is possible to remove one of them?  The documentation does not say anything about that.

Comment: @VladIancu, it's Github, you can ask an author, by creating a new issue :-) Glad that you find it useful

Comment: I'll try, but since the last update was in 2013, I doubt it will answer :(

Answer (score 0):

For anyone needing to create a similar Seekbar like me:

This library was exactly what I needed, except the fact that it has 2 thumbs, and no way to eliminate one of them.

https://github.com/edmodo/range-bar

[image]

I have devised a little "hack" for this: When you initialize the Range-Bar, you can set the thumb indices via this method, as stated in the [wiki:](https://github.com/edmodo/range-bar/wiki)

```
RangeBar rangebar = (RangeBar) findViewById(R.id.rangebar);
rangebar.setThumbIndices(5,5); //indices example
```

And when a thumb index changes, in the following method you set the seekbar thumbs to the same position:

```
rangebar.setOnRangeBarChangeListener(new RangeBar.OnRangeBarChangeListener() {
@Override
public void onIndexChangeListener(RangeBar rangeBar, int leftThumbIndex, int rightThumbIndex) { 
    //Code using the leftThumbIndex and rightThumbIndex to update the index values.
    rangeBar.setThumbIndices(leftThumbIndex, leftThumbIndex);
    }
});
```

Hope it will be of use for anyone.

Thanks everyone for the help!

Cheers!